# Wordpress: getting page name for blog, not home page

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I developed my site with a fine WP developer (if anyone's interested, lemme know), but he is out of town and I am still resolving one thing.  I have a border image under the navigation tabs which is conditional for the navigation based on page.  He's advising me to add the following:

> At the top of the template file type '"echo $pagename;"'
>   This should then output the name of the page as WP sees it.

Here's the home page with no borders under the tabs Blog, Humor, Consulting

> http://www.leesachs.com

Click on Humor or Consulting and you'll see the border I'm trying to get

There is a border under those tabs that SHOULD be under 'Blog' but it is not appearing

Here's the conditional statements for all 3 (assume all the paths and images are in place)  We also tried changing replacing
    (is_home()) 
with
    ($pagename == "blog") 
but that didn't work

```
if (is_home()){
echo ('<img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/blog_bar.jpg" alt="blog page     border" />');
}elseif ($pagename == "humor"){
echo ('<img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/humor_bar.jpg" alt="humor page     border" />');
}elseif ($pagename == "consulting"){
echo ('<img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/consulting_bar.jpg"     alt="consulting page border" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to blog page, you won't see the img html. I think blog page not the home page, so make that as home page or you can put the other condition that you mentioned ($pagename == "blog") in that case I guess the pagename is not "blog" but something else.

**[EDIT]**OK so the blog page is not the home page if you navigate to http://leesachs.com/ and http://leesachs.com/blog/ they both are different pages. Answering this is difficult without looking at Wordpress backend.

Comment: Thanks @Abdullah...you got it the blog is not the home page.  As for WP backend, from the admin screen of course I have it set that front page is static to "Home" and the posts page is "Blog."  Nothing unusual there.  When you say backend, not sure where else to go?  Could it be something in MySQL?

Comment: Can you try with $pagename == "Blog" condition ?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it didn't change anything ... Didn't break anything either.